# A question of sequence and series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a positive integer triad (a,b,c) such that a/b + b/c + c/a =2017/1000. If so, give at least one example.
I tried solving this using AP-GP-HP inequality but get some complex thing.
Please help me.

Comment: what can you say by reasoning on denominators ?

Comment: What does this have to do with sequences and series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum of $f(a,b,c) = a/b + b/c + c/a$ for $a, b, c > 0$ is on $a=b=c$, where $f(a,a,a) = 3$.  Since this is greater than $2017/1000$, there are no solutions.

Comment: Well I have another method...I have posted it....If u could just see it once and judge it...It would be nice. Thank u.

Comment: (Unrelated and feel free to ignore) Could you please have a look at [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72685/sequence-puzzle) or [these](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81473/reasoning-of-puzzles)?

Answer (score 0):

Applying AM-GM inequality
We get,
((abc)/(bca))^1/3 ≤ ((a/b) + (b/c) + (c/a))/3

1 ≤ ((a/b) + (b/c) + (c/a))/3

3≤ (a/b) + (b/c) + (c/a)

But since 2017/1000< 3 
Therefore there does not exist any such triad.